# How to grep file name in chef and create a directory off of it?

Tags: iteration, chef-infra

I have a directory called "executables" that contains 3 binaries; "x", "y" and "z". My "executables" directory is contained in my "files" folder of my chef cookbook.

In my main recipe, how can I write my code so that 3 new directories are created  as follows:

```
"/workdir/x/5.2/" # where the binary "x" is contained in directory : "/workdir/x/5.2/"
"/workdir/y/5.2/" # where the binary "y" is contained in directory : "/workdir/y/5.2/"
"/workdir/z/5.2/" # # where the binary "z" is contained in directory : "/workdir/z/5.2/"
```

Is there a way I can do within a for loop. Rather than having three different "cookbook_file" resource blocks?  Perhaps there is a way to grep the binary name and create a directory off of it and then place that binary within that directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `cookbook_file` resource can be used, but the target directory must be present/created prior to copying. We can iterate over the "executables" and create that directory (if required) and copy the files.

Considering `files/default/executables` of cookbook:

```
x
y
z
```

Then in your recipe

```rb
%w(
  x
  y
  z
).each do |exe|
  directory "/workdir/#{exe}/5.2" do
    recursive true
  end
    
  cookbook_file "/workdir/#{exe}/5.2/#{exe}" do
    source "executables/#{exe}" 
  end
end
```

You can also look at the `remote_directory` [resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/remote_directory), which will dynamically create directories and copy the files.

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to do it so I do not have to hard code the  the x y and z executables within  %w(x y z)? Meaning, for every file within the directory, create a directory for that executable?

Comment: You could have a node attribute for that. E.g.: in `attributes/default.rb`: `default['my_cookbook']['executables']` and assign it the values you need. Then you can iterate over `node['my_cookbook']['executables'].each` instead of `%w(x y z).each`